# Getting /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: git-bash, drush

I have a problem with my Gitbash. whenever I am running below drush command I am getting error

command : drush @site sqlq "select * from tablename"

error : /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I tried to run simple drush commands like drush @site cc all and they are working fine.

Is this issue related to system configurations or any environment variable related problem? I tried to run this command in other system and it is working fine. I am not able to figure out what is the issue here Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Git bash means [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Check first your .bashrc (in `%USERPROFILE%`): if you have one, make sure it does not echo any string to stdout when executed (you can see that by typing in git bash `source /c/Users/<You>/.bashrc`.

Then try again with a git bash done from a CMD where you set a simplified PATH

For testing, download [`PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe`][2] and uncompress its content anywhere you want.

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Add also the PATH for the `drush` command, then try again said command in a git bash done from that CMD with that simplified PATH.