# How to escape { in git alias

Tags: bash, git, escaping, git-alias

I'm tryingto write log alias

```
git config --global --replace-all alias.lol6 "! f() { echo "\$1"; git --no-pager log --oneline  --graph -15 \${@}; }; f"
```

and use it like  this:

```
git lol5 '@{-1}'
git log '@{-1}'  #works
```

but the commit-ish passged to git is @-1

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '@-1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
```

I read  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39616600/1212203) but didn't understand how to use it

Thanks
Boaz

Some more information, tried @vonc advise

```
git config --global --replace-all alias.lol6 '! f() { echo "$1"; git --no-pager log --oneline  --graph -15 ${@}; }; f'
```

Got same results, turn on GIT_TRACE

```
git lol6 @{-1}
20:20:37.454153 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-lol6 '@{-1}'
20:20:37.454153 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-lol6 '@{-1}'
20:20:37.463150 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: ' f() { echo "$1"; git --no-pager log --oneline  --graph -15 ${@}; }; f' '@{-1}'
@-1
22:20:37.607150 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git log --oneline --graph -15 @-1
fatal: ambiguous argument '@-1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Git is adding '' around first argument

But !!!, if I tried

```
git lol6 HEAD
20:30:35.621257 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: ' f() { echo "$1"; git --no-pager log --oneline  --graph -15 ${@}; }; f' HEAD
```

Git doesn't add '' around HEAD

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using string quotes `'` instead of double-quotes: less escaping to do in your case.

See this example, done in a git bash session.

```
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/git$ 
git config --global --replace-all alias.lol6 \
  '! f() { echo "$1"; git --no-pager log --oneline  --graph -15 ${@}; }; f'
```

First, I check that I can print a bogus argument:

```
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/git$ git config --global --replace-all alias.lol6 '! f() { echo "$1"; git --no-pager log --oneline  --graph -15 ${@}; }; f'
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/git$ git lol6 e
e
fatal: ambiguous argument 'e': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Then I try, without any quotes when calling the alias: **`git lol6 @{-1}`**

```
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/git$ git lol6 @{-1}
@{-1}
* 29533fb168 (tmp2) RelNotes: the eleventh batch
*   dc8fb4dd7e Merge branch 'rb/quick-install-doc'
|\
| * 65289e9dcd install-doc-quick: allow specifying what ref to install
```

---

If the alias/command above does not work, always double-check with a [**simplified PATH**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245596/6309):

```
set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

The [OP Boaz Nahum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173533/boaz-nahum) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646642/how-to-escape-in-git-alias#comment88371707_50646987):

> using 'simplified PATH' -it works.
>   Now what it means ? Why it works ?

It works because there is no telling what is in your original PATH, in `C:\Windows\System32` and other folders placed *before* Git, and overshadowing some of the Git executable.

> How can I make standard Git installation work too ?

Simply replace `c:\path\to\latest\git` above by your own Git current installation path.

Then set your `PATH`:

```
set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
```

Next, add all your other folders form your original `%PATH%`, and *always* end with `C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`.
That way, you:

- start with the most specific (Git: `git/bin`, `git/usr/bin`, `git/ming64/bin`), making sure Git is working as expected
- go on with more general application paths (the ones you had in your original PATH)
- end with the most general PATH of all: the OS Windows ones (the `C:\windows\system32\...` ones)

By going from the most specific to the most general, you lower the rate of "unexpected behavior" of your installed software.

Comment: Thanks @vonc, Tried you suggestion without any luck, add 'set -x' and it clear that @-1 is passed to git.
Maybe it related for bash implementation come with git under windows, will try on linux

Comment: What is your OS and your got version?

Comment: You asked while I'm typing :) Windows 10, git 2.17.0.windows.1

Comment: I will try simple bash script not related to git

Comment: Then the answer illustrates exactly what I typed and see in a Windows Git bash session

Comment: From bash (mingw64)  'function f() { echo $1; }' 
f @{-1}
works just fine.
The same git alias display @-1
git config --global --replace-all alias.lol6 '! f() { echo $1;  }; f'
git lol6 @{-1}
I got @-1

Comment: @BoazNahum And if you type what I typed, does it work?

Comment: @BoazNahum Also, try again with the same commands and git bash, but using a simplified PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245596/6309

Comment: No, it doesn't work if I typed what you typed.
Will try  simplified PATH

Comment: Did you test it with the simplified PATH I recommended above?

Comment: using 'simplified PATH' -it works. Now what it means ? Why it works ? How can I make standard Git installation work too ? MANY THANKS !!!

Comment: I knew it. The standard PATH on Windows is often an ungodly mess. Try and add your original PATH folders *after* the current simplified one.

Comment: But the simplified one is composed of portable git- and I can’t use it. Can you try to explain what is important and what is not in your change so I can refine it ?

Comment: Why can't you use it? Or why can't you reorder your path in order to put your own git first, and system32 last?

Comment: I just said that I can't user portable Git. And I don't understand what is important the order or the fact that we use portable git. I will try to reorder using installed git. Still I don't understand what the issue is. I wonder if you can spend some time and trying to explain it to me.

Comment: @BoazNahum My edited answer precisely addresses the fact you cannot use the portable Git.

Comment: @BoazNahum The edited answer is me spending some time  and trying to explain to you what the issue is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172523/discussion-between-boaz-nahum-and-vonc).